# Finding subset sum recursively producing incorrect output

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, subset-sum

Followed [this method (pdf)](http://www.wou.edu/~broegb/Cs345/SubsetSum.pdf) to implement a recursive solution, but I think it is buggy. I have exactly implemented it as described in the pdf file.

The output of the code below is wrong. It shows the target locations. The target array contains bit representation of the numbers that should be added to get the sum.

Placing the `binary[i] = 1` in `else if` condition fixes the problem, but it doesn’t make sense.

Is it possible to clarify what is the right solution?

```
#define SIZE(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
int binary[100];
void foo(int target, int i, int sum, int *a, int size) {
    binary[i] = 1;
    if (target == sum+a[i]) {
        int j;
        for (j=0;j<size;j++)
            printf("%d\n", binary[j]);
        return;
    } else if ((i+1 < size) && (sum + a[i] < target)) {
        foo(target, i+1, sum + a[i], a, size);
    }
    if ((i+1 < size) && (sum +a[i+1] <= target)) {
        binary[i] = 0;
        foo(target, i+1, sum, a, size);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, target =10,a[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 100};
    foo(target, 0, 0, a, SIZE(a));
}
```

Current output: `0 1 1 1 1`

Expected output: `0 1 1 1 0`

Comment: which language? C? C++? please tag accordingly

Comment: Please add the current output, and the right output you'd expect instead. Also try to make it easier for yourself and don't use `t`, `i` and `a`, but use meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
int binary[100];

void show(int* p, int size) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        printf("%d\n", p[j]);
}

void foo(int target, int i, int sum, int *a, int size) {
    if (sum == target) {
        // solution found
        show(binary, size);
    } else if (sum < target && i < size) {
        // try both branches
        // 1. current value used
        binary[i] = 1;
        foo(target, i + 1, sum + a[i], a, size);
        // 2. current value skipped
        binary[i] = 0;
        foo(target, i + 1, sum, a, size);
    } else {
        // no solution on this path
    }
}

int main() {
    int target = 10;
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 100};
    foo(target, 0, 0, a, SIZE(a));
}
```

Explanation:

- Let's speak only about `i`, `sum` and `binary` because everything else is constant from this algorithm's perspective.
- Our aim is to select individual elements from `a` whose sum is equal to `target`. When we reach this situation we are done and our only work is to `show` the solution.
- The algorithm can proceed only if our current `sum` is still below the `target`, and we haven't reached the end of `a` yet.
- There are always two possibilities: *Use* the current element or *skip* it. Both are investigated recursively.
- The procedure must leave zero in the appropriate position of `binary`, otherwise it would provide misleading results at various levels of [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). For this reason the *use* branch is investigated first.

Comment: @newbie_old You are right. I've fixed my answer. I had to change the condition `i + 1 < size` to `i < size`, and also exchange the "used" and "skipped" branches in order to leave zero in the `binary` array for other solutions possibly found by [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).